# Cannot do MKAnnotationView animate drop with custom image

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I have successfully changed MKAnnotationView to use my custom image with the following code snippet. However, my problem is that once I enable default pin animation using

```
   annotationView.animatesDrop = YES;
```

The custom image is gone and default red pin is used. Is there any way to fix this?
Thanks

```
 - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(MyAnnotation  *)annotation
 {
    if  ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    return nil;
// try to dequeue an existing pin view first
static NSString* identifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";

MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
if (annotationView == nil) {
    annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    annotationView.enabled = YES;
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    //!!!!!!!annotationView.animatesDrop = YES;!!!!!!!!!!
} else {
    annotationView.annotation = annotation;
}

  annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bla.png"];
 return annotationView;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try smth like this:

```
- (void)loadView {
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [self.view setClipsToBounds:YES];

    MKMapView *mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, self.view.frame.size.width - 20, self.view.frame.size.height - 20)];
    mapView.delegate = self;
    [mapView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
    mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
    [self.view addSubview:mapView];
}

#pragma mark - MKMapView Delegate Implementation

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views {   
    for (MKAnnotationView *pin in views) {
        //UIButton *detailsButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        //[detailsButton addTarget:self action:@selector(detailsButtonAct:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        pin.canShowCallout = YES;
        //pin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = detailsButton;
        CGRect endFrame = pin.frame;
        pin.frame = CGRectOffset(pin.frame, 0, -230);

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.45f];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

        pin.frame = endFrame;

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    static NSString *AnnotationViewID = @"annotationViewID";
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[map dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];

    if (annotationView == nil)
        annotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationViewID] autorelease];

    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"map_pin.png"];
    annotationView.annotation = annotation;

    [annotationView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selected" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:@"pinSelected"];
    [annotationView setEnabled:YES];

    return annotationView;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you need to do the animation yourself. I didn't think of the Offset but of course it solves all the coordinate issues with maps and views.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone wants to do this the block-based way instead of the begin/commit way (which is recommended from IOS 4 onwards):

```
...
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
                         pin.frame = endFrame;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         if (finished) {
                             // Do some action upon completion of animation
                         }
                     }];
```

Thanks for the answer demon, really helpful